# UITableViewCell Fixing the Formatting of the Label When Delete is Enabled

Tags: ios, ios6

Here is what is going on:

[image]

I am using iOS 6 and auto layouts. how can I fix this problem without having to write code. There are two constraints on the label.

Width should be <= 130 
Height should be <= 55

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the hacks!

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VegetableNoteCell *noteCell = (VegetableNoteCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *constraints = [noteCell.noteDescriptionLabel constraints];
    NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = constraints[1];
    [horizontalConstraint setConstant:180.0];

}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    VegetableNoteCell *noteCell = (VegetableNoteCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *constraints = [noteCell.noteDescriptionLabel constraints];
    NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalConstraint = constraints[1];
    [horizontalConstraint setConstant:125.0];

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

}
```